# Include static C++ library to Objective C project

Tags: c++, objective-c, shared-libraries

I want to create an C++ so library and include it in my Objective C code. I work in XCode.
Here is C++ code:

--------------core.cpp----------

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

extern "C" void my_sort(std::vector<int>& a) throw()
{
 sort(a.begin(), a.end()); // this is std::vector's sort function 
}
```

So I want to create the so library for including it in the Obejctive C code.
How to include or import it ? .. I want to call my_sort() function ?

THanks !

Answer (score 0):

The trouble here is that your function has external C linkage. Hence it cannot use arguments of type `std::vector`, neither `throw` declarations as these are C++ stuff.

To include it into your objective C code, you have to write the accompanying header file, that will declare your exported function. It will be much easier to export it once you will have removed all references to C++ from its interface. It will also avoid the need to include the C++ headers.

Then, to use it from your Objective C code, #include your header file, and give the linker information to your library.

Comment: I've done all this, but the linking seems FUBAR in Xcode. What does "give the linker information" actually mean, with Xcode?